# Invoke A Multipart REST Service with vaadin

Tags: rest, vaadin, multipartform-data, vaadin7, multipart

I need to send a Multipart file data to REST service from  vaadin . How can I achieve it ? .. ( web service API is listed below)

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String[] handleFileUpload( 
            @RequestParam( value="file" , required=false) MultipartFile file , @RequestParam( value="title" , required=false)String title ,@RequestParam( value="description" , required=false)String description ){

// file uploading logic....

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with vaadin. You have to implement a REST client which will send a form post. There are a lot of libraries for REST clients in java, ask google

Answer (score 1):

When working with external HTTP based services in Java / VAADIN I'm ussualy using very nice JODD Java library specificaly http://jodd.org/doc/http.html

To post attachment to URL as explained in question, simply use something like this:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest
        .post("http://server:8080/upload")
        .form(
            "file", new File("c:\\a.jpg.zip")
        );

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.send();
```

HttpRequest is object from JODD library. You can include JODD into maven config e.g. http://jodd.org/download/